# How to extract certain pattern from a url using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some bunch of urls like below

```
https://data.hova.com/strap/nik/sql_output1574414532.89.zip

https://data.hova.com/strap/asr/sql_output1574414532.89.zip

https://data.hova.com/strap/olr/sql_output1574414532.89.zip
```

Now I want to extract just the `zip` file name ie `sql_output1574414532.89.zip`, `sql_output1574414532.89.zip`, `sql_output1574414532.89.zip` respectively.

Now I could have used a simple `split` to get the filenames but if you observe, the directory name before the `zip` file changes like `nik`, `asr`, `olr` etc.

So I want to use `regex` so that I only look at anything that starts with **sql** and ends with **zip**.

So this is what I did

```
import re

string = "https://data.hova.com/strap/nik/sql_output1574414532.89.zip"
pattern = r'^sql\.zip$'
match = re.search(pattern, string)
print(match)
```

But the `match` comes as `None`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `r'^sql\.zip$'` matches only one string: "sql.zip".

For your purpose you need something like `sql.+zip$`, or, if you expect that `sql` string can be encountered in URL before file name, change it to `sql[^/]+zip$`.